# Spring will not start : error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: spring, linux-mint

I have a Linux Mint, while qtarting the game in springlobby I get the following message in stdout and game do not start.

```
/home/$(whoami)/.spring/engine/103.0/spring: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I get the shared library?

Comment: I can get only the 100 engine.

Answer (score 0):

What about sudo apt-get install curl ?

Comment: This install an older version of curl which have no `libcurl.so.4` but an older version.